# Button to Copy a Text Box

Tags: javascript, html

I need a simple script that gives me a button that when clicked will copy the contents of a text input box to the clipboard.  Or it could be a script that when you click on the text input box, automatically copies the contents to the clipboard and displays a "Copy" message next to the text input box.

I've seen them all over the web, but can't find the code for one now.

Comment: What are you trying to copy *to*—another form field, a JavaScript variable, or the clipboard?

Comment: Maybe I should have clarified that I'm looking for it to copy the contents of the text input box to the clipboard.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-clipboard-in-javascript

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

This example uses [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

Assuming an input box with an id of `foo`, and a button with an id of `clickme`, here's how I'd do it:

```
var inputText = "";
$("#clickme").click(function() {
    inputText = $("#foo").val();
});
// inputText now has the input box's value
```

**Edit:**

After your clarification, I now understand what you are trying to do. Unfortunately, flash 10 broke most of the methods to do this. However, some great people wrote [ZeroClipboard](http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/), which is fully compatible with flash 10 and makes it really easy to accomplish this task. [Their wiki](http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/wiki/Instructions) explains usage.

Comment: This sample seems to be missing the actual sample

Comment: +1 for jQuery.  IMHO nobody should use javascript without it*

Comment: Sorry, I clarified that I need it to copy to the clipboard.